# Firebase Firestore Multiplayer Game Matchmaking

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So I want to make a multiplayer game using Firebase Firestore that involves matchmaking two players. I have a collection of game objects and each game has a creator and joiner field (just the UID of the users). I'm trying to attempt to join created games and am struggling with it. Here is what I currently have.

```
 fun findOpenGame(onComplete: (gameFound: Boolean, gameObject: Game?, gameRef: DocumentReference?) -> Unit) {
        gamesCollectionRef
                .whereEqualTo("joiner", null)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        for (document: DocumentSnapshot in task.result) {
                            val game: Game = document.toObject(Game::class.java)!!
                            if (game.joiner == null) {
                                document.reference.update("joiner", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                                            onComplete(true, game, document.reference)
                                        }
                                        .addOnFailureListener {
                                            Log.e(FirestoreUtil.javaClass.simpleName, "Couldn't connect to game")
                                        }
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        //no games to join
                        onComplete(false, null, null)
                    }
                }
    }
```

BTW, I'm really new to Kotlin so please feel free to tell me if I'm missing something obvious. I also have to deal with the issue of multiple users trying to join the same match at once and messing things up. Any advice helps :)

Comment: You say you want to "to join created games". What do you mean? Can you also add your database structure for a better understanding?

Comment: If there are no open games, then the user will create a new game object and upload it to the games collection. Every document (game) has a creator and a joiner. My whole database consists of a games collection and a users collection.